# How can I change the border colour of a <td> using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, html-table

I'm trying to change the colour of a `<td>` in my `.html` file. Here is what I have but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working.

My `.html` file:

```
<table>
    <tr id = "table_row">
        <td>Computers</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>Location</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And now my `.js` file:

```
function changeBorderColor() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table_row").getElementsByTagName("td");
    table.style.borderColor = "red";
}
```

Why doesn't my `<td>` change colour when I activate the `changeBorderColor()` function? Thanks in advance for any tips and help!

Comment: getElementsByTagName is a NodeSet

Comment: Also, how do you call `changeBorderColor`?

Comment: Are you using jQuery by chance? Or are you limited to using vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getElementsByTagName()` method will return an array of elements matching the tag selector. So you would need to iterate througth it to change each element:

***Simple example:***

```
function changeBorderColor() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table_row").getElementsByTagName("td");
    for(var i=0; i<table.length; i++) {
        var td = table[i];
        td.style.borderColor = "red";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.getElementsByTagName("td")` returns a NodeList, you will have to loop through each `td` and assign the `border` individually.

You also need to specify the `borderWidth` and `borderStyle` properties.

```js
function changeBorderColor() {
  var td = document.getElementById("table_row").getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
    td[i].style.borderColor = "red";
    td[i].style.borderWidth = "1px";
    td[i].style.borderStyle = "solid";
  }
}
changeBorderColor()
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="table_row">
    <td>Computers</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Location</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Jquery here.For example:

```
function changeBackground(){

$("td").css("border","2px solid red");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use jQuery, here is a slightly more verbose example:

```
$('#table_row td').each(function(index){

   //Do something with each result. In this case - add a border
   $(this).css({ 'border': '1px solid red' });

});
```

Here is a fiddle for the jQuery example: http://jsfiddle.net/k3d6peLy/

Alternatively, if you don't have to worry about supporting anything before IE8, you could also use JavaScript's 'querySelectorAll()' method:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#table_row td');

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].style.border = '1px solid red';
}
```

Here is a fiddle for the 'querySelectorAll()' example: http://jsfiddle.net/k3d6peLy/1/